# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' while mapping a function through my dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, map-function

I'm trying to map a function `process_image` to the dataset. This function calls another function, `get_label`. In `get_label`, I'm trying to retrieve the label's name from images.

The file path is like this: `C:\\Users\\sis\\Desktop\\test\\0002_c1s1_000451_03.jpg`. The label is number `0002`.

[image]

```
def get_lab(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    part=parts[-1].numpy().decode().split('_')[0]
    label=tf.strings.to_number(part)
    return label
```

Comment: This needs more context. Are you using this function in `Dataset.map`? All `tf.data` code is run non-eagerly as graph code, meaning the tensors in your code are only symbolic and cannot be converted to numpy arrays.

Comment: yes i m using it in  Dataset.map, i'm new to tensorflow, i just know that eager mode is activated by defalut in tf 2 & above! also this code works okey when i test it on single path, the problem is with the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I didn't understand exactly where the error was, I think the previous code mixed eager mode and graph mode, so I changed the code of `get_label` function and it worked!

```
def get_lab(file_path):

    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)[-1]
    part=tf.strings.split(parts, sep='_')[0]
    print(part)
    label=tf.strings.to_number(part)
    return label
```

Answer (score 0):

You may applied to folder name that create sufficeints used of external programs.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

def get_lab(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    part=parts[-2].numpy().decode().split('.')[0]
    label=tf.strings.to_number(part)
    return label.numpy()

directory = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt\\01.tif\\"
print( 'label as number: ' + str(get_lab( directory )) )

directory = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\"
print( 'classname: ' + str(tf.io.gfile.listdir(
    directory
))
)
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
label as number: 1.0
classname: ['Candidt Kibt', 'Pikaploy']

F:\temp\Python>
```

Comment: This answer does not provide the solution to this question.

Comment: my code works okey when i pass individual path for one image, the problem is when i pass it with map function on the dataset, it gives me this error : train_ds = images_ds.map(process_image)